# How do I include a .bbx file in my .tex file?

Tags: biblatex

How do I set a .bbx file that contains some customisations inside my actual .tex file? I want to move all the changes I've made to the "numeric" biblatex behaviour somewhere outside of my main .tex file.

Comment: You can use a biblatex.cfg file. See page s 3.2.1 of the biblatex documentation.

Comment: You can also build your on style (`.bbx` and `.cbx` files). In those files you can load a (standard) style (well, any style actually) via `\RequireBibliographyStyle`. Have a look at [`ieee.bbx`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/blob/master/ieee.bbx) for example. See also §4.2 *Bibliography Styles* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).